# unable to map topics to specified index in kafka elasticsearch connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

tried to map topic "name: localtopic"  to index "name:indexoftopic" ,
its creating two new index in elastic search "localtopic and indexoftopic" and data of topic visible only in topic name index "localtopic", no errors in connector shown ( distributed mode )

my config is

```
 "config" : {
  "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max" : "1",
  "topics" : "localtopic", 
  "topic.index.map" : "localtopic:indexoftopic",
  "connection.url" : "aws elasticsearch url",
  "type.name" : "event",
  "key.ignore" : "false",
  "schema.ignore" : "true",
  "schemas.enable" : "false",
  "transforms" : "InsertKey,extractKey",
  "transforms.InsertKey.type" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
  "transforms.InsertKey.fields" : "event-id",
  "transforms.extractKey.type" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
  "transforms.extractKey.field" : "event-id"
 }
```

index name:indexoftopic is created in elasticsearch but data is seen by index_name:localtopic
kafkaversion:2.3  connectorversion:5   elasticsearchversion:3.2.0

even in logs INFO -- topics.regex = "", I don't know ihis option, can anyone suggest. how to use this ???

Comment: You don't need topics.regex, you' already have topics... By version 5, do you mean 5.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below worked for me, but, I was mapping only 1 topic to a different index name

```
"transforms": "addSuffix",  
"transforms.addSuffix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.addSuffix.regex": "topic1.*",
"transforms.addSuffix.replacement": "index1",
```

so, with above transforms any topic such as `topic1, topic1-test, topic1<anystring>`
will be mapped to `index1`

alternately, you can use the topic name in replacement as well, by changing the last 2 lines as below, this will pick

```
    "transforms.addSuffix.regex": "topic.*",
    "transforms.addSuffix.replacement": "index$1",
```

basically, you can replace partial or full topic name using regex.

Answer (score 2):

It is advised that you use RegexRouter transform instead, if you look at the config options

> `topic.index.map`
>
> This option is now deprecated. A future version may remove it completely. Please use single message transforms, such as RegexRouter, to map topic names to index names.

Comment: How to use Regex Router can you specify,, for multiple topic to same index, ex: topic1:index, topic2:index, topic3:index   like this in regex router

Comment: I don't know. I would try something like this `"type.name" : "index"` ... `"transforms.Regex.regex":"topic(.*)", ... `  ... `"transforms.Regex.replacement":"topic"` https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html

Comment: The real question is why you have "topic1, topic2, topic3" at all? Surely you could use partitions rather than sequentially named topics? Personally, I use one connector definition per topic, not group them